# `No routes matched location "/" ` warning shown on the console

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a small project and got an error/warning like above title.

Here is my `Index.jsx`:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

import { App } from "./components/app";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Suspense>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`App.jsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import Sidebar from "../sidebar/Sidebar";
import TopNav from "../topnav/TopNav";
import { AppRoutes } from "../AppRoutes";

import ThemeAction from "../../store/actions/ThemeAction";

import "./App.scss";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  contentStyle: {
    margin: "30px auto",
  },
});

export const App = () => {
  const themeReducer = useSelector((state) => state.ThemeReducer);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const themeClass = localStorage.getItem("themeMode", "theme-mode-light");

    const colorClass = localStorage.getItem("colorMode", "theme-mode-light");

    dispatch(ThemeAction.setMode(themeClass));

    dispatch(ThemeAction.setColor(colorClass));
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        render={(routeProps) => (
          <div className={`app ${themeReducer.mode} ${themeReducer.color}`}>
            <Sidebar routeProps={routeProps} />
            <div className="app__content">
              <TopNav />
              <div className="app__content-main">
                <ToastContainer />
                <Container className={classes.contentStyle} maxWidth="sm">
                  <AppRoutes />
                </Container>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

And `AppRoutes.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";

import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import Customers from "../pages/Customers";
import { Dashboard } from "../pages/Dashboard";
import { UserLogin } from "./User/Login";
import { UserSignup } from "./User/Signup/UserSignup";

export const AppRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route index path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
      <Route path="customers" component={<Customers />} />
      <Route path="userLogin" element={<UserLogin />} />
      <Route path="userSignup" element={<UserSignup />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

And the project is not running) I mean white blank on browser window while there is no error except `index.tsx:25 No routes matched location "/"` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer any `render` (*or `component` or `children` function props*). Remove the `Routes` and `Route` component in `App`. You will also update `Sidebar` to access the `location` object via hook.

App

```
return (
  <div className={`app ${themeReducer.mode} ${themeReducer.color}`}>
    <Sidebar routeProps={routeProps} />
    <div className="app__content">
      <TopNav />
      <div className="app__content-main">
        <ToastContainer />
        <Container className={classes.contentStyle} maxWidth="sm">
          <AppRoutes />
        </Container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

Sidebar

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const activeItem = sidebar_items.findIndex(
    (item) => item.route === location.pathname
  );

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <div className="sidebar__logo">
        <img src={logo} alt="company logo" />
      </div>
      {sidebar_items.map((item, index) => (
        <Link to={item.route} key={index}>
          <SidebarItem
            title={item.display_name}
            icon={item.icon}
            active={index === activeItem}
          />
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

AppRoutes

Remove the `index` prop from the `"/"` route. When you specify an index route the `path` prop is ignored. Also, make sure all the routes are correctly using the `element` prop.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="customers" element={<Customers />} />
  <Route path="userLogin" element={<UserLogin />} />
  <Route path="userSignup" element={<UserSignup />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit no-routes-matched-location-warning-shown-on-the-console]

Comment: thanks but the same error) it didn't help

Comment: @MukhriddinShakhriyorov It should work. Try restarting your development server. You may need to do a clear cache/hard reload.

Comment: I did as you told) the same error) I guess mistake is related to another case

Comment: @MukhriddinShakhriyorov I could be, perhaps. Think you could try creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: what about anydesk or teamviewer? do you use it?

Comment: here is I created a repo on GitHub) https://github.com/mshakhriyorov/tua-react-admin-main

Comment: @MukhriddinShakhriyorov I'm checking it out now, but I do immediately see that in that repo the code is rendering routes using the v5 `Route` component API, not the v6 API using the `element` prop. Are you sure the repo is the same code you are asking about in your question here?

Comment: Yes the project was running on V5) and my goal is to run the project on v6

Comment: @MukhriddinShakhriyorov Ok, I see that I missed calling some issues out in the code you shared. I've updated my answer and added the fork of *your* repo I've fixed up in codesandbox. Please do take another look.